# Loading Resources in background mode at DirectX 9.0

Tags: directx, directx-9

I have made an 3D Game with DirectX9.0.

I want to load resources in background mode by use thread.

Here is my code.

----------------Attakc.h---------------------------

```
#define AFXBEGINTHREAD(pfnThreadProc,pParam) AfxBeginThread(pfnThreadProc, pParam, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,0,CREATE_SUSPENDED,NULL)

CWinThread* g_pThread  = NULL;

volatile bool g_bExitThread  = true;

CCriticalSection g_csExitThread;
```

----------------Attakc.cpp---------------------------

...

```
case WM_START:

    if(wParam >= 0 && wParam < 18)
    {
        g_csExitThread.Lock();
        g_bExitThread = false;
        g_csExitThread.Unlock();
        g_pThread = AFXBEGINTHREAD(ThreadFunc,0);
         if(NULL == g_pThread)
         {
             MessageBoxW(0,L"Failed to Create Thread",0,0);
         }
         g_pThread->m_bAutoDelete = TRUE;
         g_pThread->ResumeThread();
         wParamTemp = wParam;
         lParamTemp = lParam;
         uMsgTemp = uMsg;
    }
```

....

```
UINT ThreadFunc(LPVOID lpParam)
{

while(true)
{

    Sleep(1);

    g_csExitThread.Lock();
    if(true == g_bExitThread)
    {
        g_csExitThread.Unlock();
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        g_csExitThread.Unlock();

        g_pApp->GotoHole(wParamTemp, lParamTemp);
        g_bExitThread = true;
        g_pApp->m_nRenderMode = RENDERMODE_SCENE;
        g_pApp->StartFlyOver();
        g_pApp->m_flyOver.bFirstTime = TRUE;
        g_pApp->m_uiLoadingMenu.m_bStart = FALSE;
        g_pApp->m_uiLoadingMenu.nTime = 0;
        g_pApp->m_uiLoadingMenu.count = 0;
    }
}
return 0L;
}
```

Then, When I run this project, E_OUTOFMEMORY error appear.(D3DXCreateTextureFromFile)

I think it belong about the thread's synchronization.

I have no experience to load resource by use thread.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you used D3DCREATE_MULTITHREADED flag when initializing d3d?